# Function to return days passed in month

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a function which will return HOW MANY DAYS have passed in the  month -1 e.g. on 07/08 would return value 6, on 08/08 return value 7 etc. or on 31/10 return value 30.

It would also be fantastic for this to roll over month on month taking into account monthly variation (28-31).

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
=day(today())-1
```

[DAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093040)
[TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)